# Why do you have to use both a compiler flag and a run-time flag to get multicore-support in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, concurrency, parallel-processing, multicore

The Haskell wiki shows that you need to both set a compilation flag and a run-time flag to get multi-core support. Why isn't using the library enough to get the correct behavior at compile time? Why can't the run-time executable detect it was compiled with -threaded and use all cores on the system unless otherwise specified? I think turning these on by default would be better. Then there could be flags to turn off or modify these features.

http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/Concurrency#Multicore_GHC says:

Compile your program using the -threaded switch.

Run the program with +RTS -N2 to use 2 threads, for example. You should use a -N value equal to the number of CPU cores on your machine (not including Hyper-threading cores).

It seems somewhat onerous to have flags one must set both at compile time and again at run time. Are these flags vestigial remains of the effort to add concurrency to GHC?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

While you're developing the program the extra `+RTS ...` shouldn't be a big deal (though I admit it struck me as odd when I first picked up Haskell).  For the final (shipped) binary you can link it with static RTS options ([GHC manual](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/users_guide/runtime-control.html#rts-hooks)) by providing a C file containing `char *ghc_rts_opts = "-N";`.

EDIT: Updating this question for GHC 7.x, there is now a way to specify RTS options at compile time:

```
ghc -threaded -rtsopts -with-rtsopts=-N
```

This 1) uses the threaded runtime system 2) Enables the RTS options 3) Sets the RTS option to use as many threads as there are cores available (use `-Nx` where `x` is a number to manually control the number of OS threads).

Comment: At least, there is a hook.  But what an ugly way to specify default RTS options.

Comment: The compiler flag is a very nice addition.

Comment: I found this thread by searching, after getting thoroughly burned.

Linux on an Intel cpu will schedule two of the most CPU intensive threads on the same core. Go look at the experimental -qa runtime flag, or (as I did) reboot your machine with hyperthreading off.

Also, on a 4 core, 8 virtual core cpu, half of all tools will report 8 cores not 4, and it depends on the cpu model. Do you trust GHC to always use 4 rather than 8 cores by default, if you simply set -N at compile time?

Parallelism isn't there yet without separate coding and runtime tuning phases.

Answer (score 8):

> Why can't the run-time executable detect it was compiled with -threaded and use all cores on the system unless otherwise specified?

That's an interesting feature request!

You could ask for it on the GHC feature tracker: http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/ReportABug

Comment: Will submit. Thanks for hint.

Comment: Considering that you can do what TomMD suggested should this bug request be considered closed?

Comment: I don't think so. After all, I could hack the entire program together in assembly if I wanted to. But I don't want to. I want compiling with -threaded to provide behavior currently enabled by placing "+RTS -N -RTS" on the command line. I think it will be much cleaner that way.

Comment: I agree with Tim on this.  While no programmer should be too put-off by having an extra header file, a little more polish doesn't hurt here.

Comment: So I submitted it and it was closed. Apparently making the runtime less obscure is not a priority of the compiler team. Re-submitted to the runtime team. Hoping for different result. http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/4319

Answer (score 4):

From GHC User guide (version 6.12.1):

> Omitting `x`, i.e. `+RTS -N -RTS`, lets the runtime choose the value of `x` itself based on how many processors are in your machine.

I suppose there's no specific reason for this not to be the default, apart from authors' vision of what should defaults be. (Note that this also enables parallel GC, which maybe sometimes isn't what you wish to be by default.)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. It addresses the "number of cores" portion of my question. That is a start. However, I'm more frustrated by having to set flags both to compile AND to run my code.

Comment: While you're developing the program this shouldn't be a big deal and for the final (shipped) binary you can link it with some [static RTS options](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/users_guide/runtime-control.html#rts-hooks) via a .h file with `char *ghc_rts_options = "-N";`

Comment: @TomMD: That is a useful hack. It would solve the issue I'm currently fighting. If you post that as a solution, I'll accept it. I'm also planning to submit a feature request as Don Steward suggested above.